# Contrato inteligente en ethereum de almacenamiento de texto

Tags: blockchain, solidity

Estoy tratando de hacer un sencillo "editor de texto" en solidity en un contrato inteligente de la red Ethereum.
Quiero hacer una **función de entrada de datos**, que recoge el texto en una STRING y una variable BYTES10 que recoge la posición del texto. Debe almacenar el texto ordenadamente para luego poder acceder a el. Y debe poder introducir nuevo texto sin sustituir el anterior.
Después una **función de salida** que devuelva el texto y las coordenadas, todas las introducidas en la red desde el inicio del contrato.
Y una **función que permita borrar datos**, por si alguno se introduce mal.
Tengo este código hasta ahora:

```
pragma solidity <0.9.0;
contract texteditor {
    struct book {
        string block;
        bytes10 coordinates;
    }
    book [] public books;
    function save(string calldata _blocks, bytes10   _coordinates) public{
        books.push(book(_blocks, _coordinates));
    }
    function read()view public returns (string){
        return books[_block][_coordinates];
    }
    function remove(string _blocks, bytes10 _coordinates) private {
        delete book[_blocks][_coordinates];
    }}
```

La función para guardar el texto creo que esta bien, pero con las otras dos estoy teniendo problemas para compilar, no se si por la versión del compilador o por que las funciones no están bien.
La información que encuentro en blogs y demás de ayuda acerca de este tema, por lo visto esta bastante anticuada en cuanto a la versión del compilador y tiende a darme problemas.
Imagino que tengo que hacer un mapping, pero no he encontrado aun la forma.
agradezco cualquier ayuda que puedan prestarme que me haga avanzar en esto.
Muchas gracias por su tiempo.